# i will repeat 10 of the following code but i ask for How do I shorten the following code?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

i will repeat 10 of the following code but i ask for How do I shorten the following code ?
Is there a short way to repeat this code without typing it all ?

```
   <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text=" view 1 "
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="36dp" />
```

Comment: Define a style containing all the common parameters and set style in `textview` . In your case style may contain , `textAlignment` , `textColor` , `textSize` and if you want `layout_width` and `layout_width` also . If you want to change value for only one `textview` , you can always override that parameter in xml file.

Comment: Hi!, If you want to repeat whole textview widget 10 times than you can create saperate xml for that textview and include it 10 times, in this way you can reuse your code. You should also use style if multiple views in your code use same attributes as @Nitish said.
Let me know if you want an example of how to use include.

Comment: Thank you and @Nitish, if you don't mind give me an example <3

Answer (score 0):

Define a style containing all the common attributes and set style in `textview` . In your case style may contain , `textAlignment` , `textColor` , `textSize` and if you want `layout_width` and `layout_width` also . If you want to change value for only one `textview` , you can always override that parameter in xml file.

```
  <style name="TextCommanStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    </style>
```

your xml file.

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        style="@style/TextCommanStyle"
        tools:text="Text 1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descTextView"
        style="@style/TextCommanStyle"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        tools:text="Text 2" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc2TextView"
        style="@style/TextCommanStyle"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/teal_200"  // override color if you want
        tools:text="Text 3" />
```

In case you want to change `textColor` or add new attribute to each textview, add to a commom style and it will reflect on all view using that style.
You can create multiple styles depending upon your use case

Answer (score 0):

Use an `include` to reused a layout without duplicating it:

https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts